# Y-scale of addRSI graph [Quantmod]

Tags: r, plot, charts, shiny, quantmod

Using Quantmod I am able to plot RSI of equity data with addRSI(), but the plot's y-scale is not adjustable and what I need is the ability to adjust the y-scale to 0 - 100 like any normal RSI plot does.

```
addRSI(n = 14) %>% print
```

[image]

However, after using the following logic to plot the RSI, the error message popped up and I do not have any clue on how to set the price parameter of RSI() as the documentation did not specify the exact meaning of this parameter.

```
print(addTA(RSI(price = 100, n = 14), yrange = c(0,100)))
```

[image]

Is there any solution where I can plot the RSI with the y-scale of 0 - 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `addRSI`, which for some reason has a fixed range based on the values, you can use `addTA` and the `yrange` option.

Using quantmod:

```
library(quantmod)

goog <- getSymbols("GOOGL", from = "2019-01-01", auto.assign = F)
rsi <- RSI(goog$GOOGL.Close)

chartSeries(goog, TA = NULL)
addTA(rsi, yrange = c(0, 100))
```

Or quantmod's chart_Series function. This adds the rsi in the 0-100 range, but it doesn't show those labels only the labels at 70 and 30.

```
chart_Series(goog)
add_RSI()
```

Using rtsplot (code straight from the help): Shows the rsi range from 0 to 100 in steps of 20 and highlights the 0-30 and 70-100 bands.

```
library(rtsplot)
layout(c(1,1,1,2))
rtsplot(goog, type = "candle")
rtsplot(rsi, type = 'l', ylim=c(0,100),
        y.highlight = c(c(0,30), c(70,100)),
        y.highlight.col = grDevices::adjustcolor(c('green','red'), 50/255)
)
```